# How to get Roles from using SimpleMembership?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, simplemembership

I am developing a MVC4 application with SimpleMembership. I have a table - "userInfo" in which I am storing user's information such as Name, Email, Address, Phone, Role etc. When I register a user, data is stored in this table and webpages_Membership. No data is stored in other Membership tables (OAuthMembership, Roles, UserInRoles).

When I login a user, it is validated using :

`if (ModelState.IsValid && WebSecurity.Login(Model.Name, Model.Password, false))`

it returns "True" but after this, I need to get the role of the registered user.

In SimpleMembership, does "Roles and UserInRoles" table provide registered user role or can I query the "userInfor" table and get roles from this table.

Please advice

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 3):

to get all available roles, assuming you have enabled Roles and added at least one..

```
var roles = (SimpleRoleProvider)Roles.Provider;

var allRoles = roles.GetAllRoles();
```

to get specific user's roles.

```
var userRoles = roles.GetRolesForUser("specificusername");
```

ref [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8h930x07%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Simple Membership does not come with any out of the box management pages for Roles. You are on your own to create them, or manage them directly through code/sql/ef etc..

Code examples...

Check for and creation of Admin role:

```
if (!Roles.RoleExists("Admin"))
     Roles.CreateRole("Admin");
```

Adding user to role on creation:

```
if (!Roles.GetRolesForUser("specificusername").Contains("Admin"))
     Roles.AddUsersToRoles(new[] {"specificusername"}, new[] {"Admin"});
```

ref [adding-security-and-membership](http://www.asp.net/web-pages/tutorials/security/16-adding-security-and-membership)

Comment: Yes, I have enabled roles in Web.Config file. Could you tell me how to add role. When I register a new user, no role is created in the webpages_roles table. Is there a different approach to add a role?

Comment: The default code generated by the Internet template does not automatically add roles to a new user. You have to add the code for it. Try looking at the SimpleRoleProvider documentation http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/webmatrix.webdata.simpleroleprovider(v=vs.111).aspx . You can add a role by using the CreateRole method and map it to a user using AddUsersToRoles method.

Answer (score 0):

You can user [Roles.GetRolesForUser Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ak75t41%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) after your user logged in

*Gets a list of the roles that the currently logged-on user is in.*

Or if you want to check whether current user is in specified role you can use [Roles.IsUserInRole Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4z6b5d42%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)