# SimpleMembership: how to get a list of users in a Role?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, simplemembership

I'm using SimpleMembership in MVC4 with Entity Framework. When create edmx, for some reasons, the table webpages_UsersInRoles does not generate class (probably it is because this table is only an association).

Now, how can I get a list users that are in a Role, i.e. All admins?

Or, I have to get all users, then check whether each is in the Admin role?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use the built-in [`Roles.GetUsersInRole` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.roles.getusersinrole(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
var usersInRole = Roles.GetUsersInRole("Admin");
```

References:

- [How to get Roles from using SimpleMembership?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20858599/how-to-get-roles-from-using-simplemembership)
- http://www.asp.net/web-pages/overview/security/16-adding-security-and-membership